# Jest mock returns undefined when testing react custom hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I created an app using Create React App I and have a custom hook that uses react query to call a service that fetches customer data. I am trying to write a unit test for the custom hook using react testing library and jest, but I can't seem to get the mock for jest.fn() to return a response. Everything I've tried returns undefined. Below is my code.

**Custom Hook**

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import CustomerService from "./CustomerService";

const useCustomers = (customerId: number) => {
  const response = useQuery(["customers", customerId], () => {
    return CustomerService.getCustomer(customerId);
  });
  const { data, isSuccess } = response;

  return { data, isSuccess };
};

export default useCustomers;
```

**Service**

```js
const getCustomer = async (customerId: number) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/customers/${customerId}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

const CustomerService = {
  getCustomer,
};

export default CustomerService;
```

**Unit Test**

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import useCustomers from "./useCustomers";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const TestingComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useCustomers(1);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Customer ID: {data.ID}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

const mockGetCustomer = jest
  .fn()
  .mockResolvedValue(() => JSON.parse('{"ID":"123"}'));
jest.doMock("./CustomerService", () => {
  return {
    getCustomer: mockGetCustomer,
  };
});

describe("useCustomers hook", () => {
  test("provides expected response from CustomerService", () => {
    mockGetCustomer.mockResolvedValue(() => JSON.parse('{"ID":"123"}'));

    render(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <TestingComponent />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    );

    const name = screen.getByText("123");
    expect(name).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "jest-mocks",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.24",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-junit": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  }
}
```

I read that setting "resetMocks": false in package.json should fix this, but that doesn't work for me. I've also tried different ways of mocking this including using a spy, but still no luck.

Comment: Does this help you : https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/testing ?

Comment: I imagine the output you're getting is something in the lines of: `Unable to find an element with the text...`. Can you confirm?

Answer (score -1):

This is quite likely because you are using `doMock` and you should be using `mock`. Jest does some magic with `mock` to ensure the mock is applied before the file in question is loaded into memory. This is not present with `doMock` so what is happening is your mock is loading after your component has already imported `./CustomerService` statically into memory -- which is too late.

Probably though you will notice problems since this also means the mock can't access things outside of its scope.

You should therefore do:

```
jest.mock("./CustomerService", () => {
  return {
    getCustomer: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(() => JSON.parse('{"ID":"123"}'));,
  };
});
```

By the way, it'd be much better to mock the actual network and not the method call. This would result in a stronger test that properly tests the service function and whole flow. You can look into [MSW](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node#setup) to do that.

Comment: The example you're providing would match the use case of `mockImplementation` for a function that returns a promise which resolves to certain value. `mockResolvedValue` is a shorthand for that. So this: `jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(JSON.parse(...))` is fine.

Comment: I tried using mock instead of doMock also, but that isn't working either.